# To check if an Integer can be divided into a Prime Partition?

Tags: python

Python function partition() that takes an integer m as input and returns True if m can be partitioned as primes and False otherwise.

I tried this Code, But this is not working for all test cases!! For Example - with the input of "185" the output should be "False", But This Code returns "True"

```
def partition(num):
    primelist = primes(num)
    for x in primelist:
        y= num-x
        if y in primelist:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def primes(num):
    primelist=[]
    for i in range(2,num + 1):
        for p in range(2,i):
            if (i % p) != 0:
                primelist.append(i)
    return primelist

print(partition(185))
```

Comment: Are you sure `primes()` is working correctly?

Comment: I found the fault, check the fix suggested by @blhsing, in this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should determine that a number is prime only after the loop finishes without finding a number that can divide the given number:

```
def primes(num):
    primelist=[]
    for i in range(2,num + 1):
        for p in range(2,i):
            if (i % p) == 0:
                break
        else:
            primelist.append(i)
    return primelist
```

Likewise, you should determine that a number is not partitionable by two primes only after the loop finishes:

```
def partition(num):
    primelist = primes(num)
    for x in primelist:
        y= num-x
        if y in primelist:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Test Case with `partition(3432)` should return **True**, With this case the code outputs **False**

Comment: I've updated my answer to point out the other issue you have with your code.